# Is it safe to use bootstrap 2 with bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

My website is written with bootstrap 2 and it will take a really long time to convert everything to bootstrap 3. I had the idea to use bootstrap 3 on new pages forward. But not sure if this is a good idea. Do you think its safe to use both bootstrap 2 and 3 in the same page?

Comment: No, it is not. Some class names used in both versions will conflict.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bootstrap 3 is not backwards compatible with Bootstrap 2. See here for information on the migration process:

http://getbootstrap.com/migration/